# add query string parameter to media file in django admin form

Tags: django, git, django-admin

I would like to append a version number to a javascript file defined in the Media class of a django admin form.

```
  class Media:    
        js = ['scripts/my_file.js?v=abc1234, ]
```

But... the url gets encoded so that the '?' becomes '%3F'.

Is there any way to have django NOT encode the URL?

As a side note, the reason I do this is to get the last git commit of my static files when the site loads by putting the following in my settings file:

```
STATIC_COMMIT = check_output(['git', 'log','-n', '1','--pretty=format:%h','--', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_app/static')]).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Then use the following in the Media class:

```
js = [f'scripts/my_file.js?{settings.STATIC_COMMIT}', ]
```

If I can do this, then I will never have to manually version media files or ask users to refresh browser cache, or worst of all have the wrong javascript (or css) file run from cache.

Comment: is that a good idea? As I understand `scripts/my_file.js?v=abc1234` this all might be in a file name? But file names does not suppert `?` marks.

Comment: @Chiefir: If I can add a script to an html file like so... `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/my_file.js?v=abc1234"></script>`... which works and is a common practice, why would it be a bad idea? Is the result of `js=[....]` being used for anything else other than adding script tags when filling the template?

Comment: This is not about JS and HTML, but about filesystem restrictions - you can't have `?` inside your filename. I guess `?v=abc1234` is some kind of Meta information, or names generated programmatically,  but not the names which are stored in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as I thought, the js media list all boils down to populating the template using the django.forms.widget function

```
    def render_js(self):
    return [
        format_html(
            '<script type="text/javascript" src="{}"></script>',
            self.absolute_path(path)
        ) for path in self._js
    ]
```

Deep down in the workings of `absolute_path` is a call to the `django.templatetags.static.static` function which does an encoding that destroys the '?' to mark the query string.

So, I created a class `VersionedMediaJS` with a custom `render_js` method which rather than touching the complex stuff, just appends the version:

```
class VersionedMediaJS():
    def __init__(self, path, version):
        self.path = forms.widgets.Media.absolute_path(None, path)
        self.version = version

    def render(self):
        html = '<script type="text/javascript" src="{0}?v={1}"></script>'
        return format_html(html, mark_safe(self.path), self.version)

    @staticmethod
    def render_js(media_object):
        html = []
        for path in media_object._js:
            if hasattr(path, 'version'):
                html.append(path.render())
            else:
                html.append(format_html('<script type="text/javascript" src="{0}"></script>', media_object.absolute_path(path)))
        return html


forms.widgets.Media.render_js = VersionedMediaJS.render_js
```

In my forms Media class I can now pass a `VersionedMediaJS()` object in addition to plain string files as so:

```
class Media():
    from django.conf import settings
    js = ["scripts/whatever.js",
          VersionedMediaJS('scripts/important.js',settings.SOURCE_COMMIT_STATIC_FILES_REV),
          VersionedMediaJS('scripts/another.js','1.2')]
```

The result will be the following inserted into the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/whatever.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/important.js?v=50cdbe0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/another.js?v=1.2"></script>
```

Since I'm driving my version number by git commit, any time a new javascript file is committed (or more precisely pulled to my prod server), the version is automatically changed.

I could do the same thing for css files, but I didn't do that here.

Special thanks to: [dmpayton/django-embedded-media](https://github.com/dmpayton/django-embedded-media) which, while addressing embedding scripts and css directly rather than versioning, provided inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a global version of static files, you can patch `django.froms.widgets.Media.render()` like that:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.forms.widgets import Media, MEDIA_TYPES

original_render = Media.render
def patched_render(self):
    result = original_render(self)
    for media_type in MEDIA_TYPES:
        result = result.replace('.%s' % media_type,
            '.%s?v=%s' % (media_type, settings.STATIC_RESOURCES_VERSION))
    return result
Media.render = patched_render
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the following approach, since as far I know, the `question mark ?` will not work.

override the `templates/admin/base_site.html` and add your `js` file + the `random_ID`

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but if you're trying to workaround browsers' cache I'd strongly suggest using a proven solution like the [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage). Really simple to use (from the documentation):

> To enable the ManifestStaticFilesStorage you have to make sure the following requirements are met:
>
> - the STATICFILES_STORAGE setting is set to 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
> - the DEBUG setting is set to False
> - you’ve collected all your static files by using the collectstatic management command

Or consider using [WhiteNoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise)